# CATIA V5 macro values from modeling in a drafting table

Tags: vb.net, catia

I need a macro to input angle values from modeling in a drafting table. Please help...
[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFTWw.gif)

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Which steps are unclear? You can use _InsertVariable_ to include an parameter as link in an drwaing text / Table

Answer (score 0):

we need more infos.. below if it can help you :

```
 Sub test()

    Dim d As DrawingDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument 'need to be a CATDrawing opened
    Dim t As DrawingTable = d.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Views.ActiveView.Tables.Item(1)

    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim p As Product = CATIA.Documents.Item("Part1.CATPart").product 'i let you find your Part

    For Each MyParam As Parameter In p.Parameters
        If MyParam.Name Like "*Angle.*" Then 'i let you find a way to get your names
            t.SetCellString(i, 1, MyParam.ValueAsString)
            i += 1
        End If
    Next



End Sub
```

---

check my website : https://www.catiavb.net/